# cannot identify image file while trying to use tensorflow on google collab

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

I am using google colaboratory and tensorflow to train a neural network to classify dogs and cats images. Where i use model.fit_generator to do training for my data. My data is loaded fine, but when once it starts iterating through the validation steps after some epochs reading through images, i get the following error described in the title:

```
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f347160a0f8>
```

The cats and dogs images i'm using are the ones downloaded from kaggle

I've seen some solution using PIL for single images on jupyter notebook, but given that google collab  uses PIL implicitly, how would i deal with this error for every image on google collab?

This is the instance of my code

```
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/data/train'
validation_data_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/data/validation'
nb_train_samples = 1000
nb_validation_Samples = 100
epochs = 10
batch_size = 20


if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
   input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
   input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale= 1. / 255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
   train_data_dir,
   target_size=(img_width, img_height),
   batch_size=batch_size,
   class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.summary()


model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))


model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = nb_validation_Samples // batch_size)


validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="binary")
```

The error itself happens at this point:

```
   model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data = validation_generator,
        validation_steps = nb_validation_Samples // batch_size)
```

Specifically, in this line:

```
validation_steps = nb_validation_Samples // batch_size)
```

Comment: Check if the image file is supported. Also, sometimes, we do get unexpected Git files, temporary files in larger datasets. Make sure that the path actually leads you to an image file ( You may check the file extension or simply use `glob` )

Comment: A good way i assume would be to check file by file if they're supported. But thats the thing, it gives error during the iteration after some epochs, assuming that epochs will train on every image. How can i make sure that images are supported during the epoch iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dataset is downloaded [from microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54765), you can use the script below to scrub it. As the comment indicates, the script is largely adopted from another SO topic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754311/unidentifiedimageerror-cannot-identify-image-file
# 1st in the answers

import os
from PIL import Image

folder_path = r'raw\PetImages'
extensions = []
for fldr in os.listdir(folder_path):
    sub_folder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, fldr)
    for filee in os.listdir(sub_folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(sub_folder_path, filee)
        print('** Path: {}  **'.format(file_path), end="\r", flush=True)
        try:
            im = Image.open(file_path)
            rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
            if filee.split('.')[1] not in extensions:
                extensions.append(filee.split('.')[1])
        except:
            print("\nWrong format file:                       ", file_path, flush=True)

print("\nValid extensions: ", repr(extensions))

'''
** Path: raw\PetImages\Cat\666.jpg  **
Wrong format file:                        raw\PetImages\Cat\666.jpg
** Path: raw\PetImages\Cat\Thumbs.db  **
Wrong format file:                        raw\PetImages\Cat\Thumbs.db
** Path: raw\PetImages\Dog\11702.jpg  **
Wrong format file:                        raw\PetImages\Dog\11702.jpg
** Path: raw\PetImages\Dog\9057.jpg  **D:\penv38\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py:811: UserWarning: Truncated File Read
  warnings.warn(str(msg))
** Path: raw\PetImages\Dog\Thumbs.db  **
Wrong format file:                        raw\PetImages\Dog\Thumbs.db

Valid extensions:  ['jpg']

Thus exclude these files: 
    Cat\666.jpg
    Dog\11702.jpg
    Dog\9057.jpg
'''
```